# GSAP: How to simultaneously tween nested attributes

Tags: javascript, object, animation, gsap

I have a `Camera` class that has two attributes that I want to animate simultaneously. I want to animate both its `distance` attribute, which is a number, and the `rotation` attribute, which has `x, y, z` elements. I've attempted the following:

**Attempt 1:**

```
TweenLite.to(this.camera, 1.0, {distance: 30, rotation.y: 10, rotation.x: 50});
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
TweenLite.to(this.camera, 1.0, {distance: 30, rotation:{y: 10, x: 50}});
```

Attempt 1 fails because it doesn't allow dot-notation inside the `vars` parameter. Attempt 2 fails silently and I get no animation whatsoever (in TweenLite v: 1.20.2). Is there a syntax I could use to trigger both distance and rotation animations simultaneously? The only method that has worked gets verbose very quickly once I have more than a few attributes to animate:

```
TweenLite.to(this.cam, 1.0, {distance: 30});
TweenLite.to(this.cam.rotation, 1.0, {y:10, x: 50});
TweenLite.to(this.cam.position, 1.0, {x:0.5, z: 3});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the [AttrPlugin](https://greensock.com/docs/Plugins/AttrPlugin)

```
TweenLite.to(this.camera, 1, {attr:{distance: 30, rotation:{y: 10, x: 50}}});
```

Comment: I just gave it a shot, but it's not working. It looks like AttrPlugin is only to modify attributes in HTML DOM elements, like `<canvas width="100">`, not to access nested JavaScript objects.

Comment: oh I see. Sorry, I didn't quite get it without seeing a codepen/jsfiddle. It looks as though you may have to do it on two lines - one to animate this.cam and one to animate this.cam.rotation (as per your verbose example). See related question in the GSAP forum here: https://greensock.com/forums/topic/7888-tween-the-properties-of-an-object-of-an-object-in-an-array/